# Has the Pi Zero ever had a Gnd on header pin 22?

Tags: pi-zero, breadboard

My documentation say's header pin 20 is ground, and pin 22 is GPIO25.

I bought a few Zero prototype boards from Schmartboard, Inc. P# 710-0016-03.  [image: Text]  Ten dollars a piece is rather expensive for this simple board.  I tried to setup the 1Wire interrface on pin 22 (GPIO25), but it would never work.  Pin 22 was stuck low.  I traced the problem back to the proto-board.  On the proto-board, pin 20 is not ground, but pin 22 is.  I asked the mfg to explain this, but they have not responded.

I'm wondering if there was any version of the Raspberry Pi Zero that had pin 22 grounded, or is Schmartboard a very poor design house?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm wondering if there was any version of the Raspberry Pi Zero that had pin 22 grounded, or is Schmartboard a very poor design house?

No, the pin out has always been the same, and the same for all models (although some models have additional buses on some of the GPIOs).